# Get background color of a webelement using rspec, ruby and capybara

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, capybara

I wanna get the background color of a web element. I am not sure of the exact command in ruby/capybara for the same.
We are using ruby, selenium and capaybara in our we application automation.

Comment: Please share some details of the element. Possible html code of the same.

Comment: I'm not sure you can get a particular attribute but if it's being defined via a css class you can get that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand `capybara`, it was not developed for the nodes manipulation, but leverages finding/matching the elements. I'd suggest to use `nokogiri` for this purposes.

[Capybara::Node::Element](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Element) provides only value and text properties.

Comment: Nokogiri doesn't process CSS so this will only work if the background color is defined in an inline style attribute and would require the OP to parse that inline style attribute

Answer (score 0):

Capybara doesn't provide direct access to the complete style of an element, however you can access it using `evaluate_script`.  Something like

```
 page.evaluate_script("window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('my_element_id'))['background-color']")
```

should return what you're looking for -- obviously if the element doesn't have an id you'd have to change the window.getElementById to a different method of locating your element.  Since you're using selenium, if you're willing to use methods that won't work with other drivers, and already have found the element in Capybara, you can do something like the following which allows you to pass the element instead of having to figure out how to find the element in the DOM again from JS

```
el = page.find(....) # however you've found the element in Capybara
page.driver.browser.execute_script("return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0])['background-color']", el.native)
```